# Check if user has delete permission on item with REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, ms-flow

Is there any way in which we can check whether a particular user has delete permission on the item?

In JSOM we have `SP.BasePermissions().has` method, but I am using MS Flow which does not support JSOM.

**Update**

List have different SharePoint group which are having Read only, contribute but no delete, full control.

Answer (score 0):

You could get item level permission by rest api.

EX：

```
/_api/web/lists(guid'9e705782-799d-423e-8ce5-41b9f098cc5e')/items(1)?$select=RoleAssignments/Member/LoginName,RoleAssignments/Member/Users/Email,RoleAssignments/RoleDefinitionBindings/Name&$expand=RoleAssignments/Member/Users,RoleAssignments/RoleDefinitionBindings
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it returns all the permission on the item, I want to check whether user has delete permission or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to delete an item when it error out throw a friendly "sorry" page